# Autolayout contraints workout a wrong result

Tags: ios, autolayout

```
[buttonCollectionView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:maskView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:buttonCollectionView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:maskHeight]];
```

I create add a view into `UICollectionView`, but why it's position is wrong?

Like this: `UIView: 0x188bbee0; frame = (0 0; 100 5)`;

```
CollectionView's frame is: UICollectionView: 0x178b8e00; frame = (0 0; 320 44);
```

Edit:

Add other constrains,

```
maskView = [[UIView alloc] init];
maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:137 / 255.0f green:209 / 255.0f blue:198 / 255.0f alpha:1];
[maskView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
maskView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[buttonCollectionView addSubview:maskView];
CGFloat maskHeight = 3;
maskXPos = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:maskView
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                           toItem:buttonCollectionView
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                         constant:(CELL_WIDTH - MASK_VIEW_WIDTH) / 2];
[buttonCollectionView addConstraint:maskXPos];
[buttonCollectionView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:maskView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:buttonCollectionView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:maskHeight]];
[maskView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:maskView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:nil
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:MASK_VIEW_WIDTH]];
[maskView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:maskView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:nil
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:maskHeight]];
```

Comment: Is it the only constraint you added? You need at least 2 constraints: one for vertical position and other one for horizontal. As I can see you only have vertical constraint.

Comment: No, there are others. Hold on, I edit the question now.

Comment: Did you tried to run `[buttonCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];` after adding all constraints?

Comment: @Max K, I add [buttonCollectionView layoutIfNeeded] in viewWillAppear, but not works.

Comment: I think the constraint, with Bottom attribute means that:
Bottom of Mask View should be Mask Height below the bottom of Collection View. Is this what you want? @anderw020

Comment: @Taha, yes, I want the bottoms both of 'maskView' and 'buttonCollectionView' on one line.

Comment: @anderw020 and are you trying to center horizontally maskView in collection view?

Comment: @Taha, no, x position (and only) of 'maskView' will be changed when user click cell of collectionView. So, I have the 'maskXPos'.

Comment: @anderw020 Added an answer below, let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this constraint for bottom:

```
[buttonCollectionView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:buttonCollectionView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:maskView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0]];//For MaskView's bottom to be aligned with bottom of Collection view distance between two should be '0'
```

Also if you are trying to center in X you might wan to see `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX`

Comment: eh, not work. UIView: 0x1575e6b0; frame = (18 -3; 28 3);
Actually, I set the constant with 'maskHeight', so I can see 'maskView', now it out of 'buttonCollectionView' rect.
I can't understand, I set bottom to bottom, but it looks like top to top...

Comment: @anderw020 whats your desired frame? I think only your Y position is causing problem.

Comment: I want the bottoms both of 'maskView' and 'buttonCollectionView' on one line.

Comment: @anderw020 I tried to mimic your scenario in Stoaryboard. See the screen short of bottom constraint( https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbfkeih1dbrr0xk/Screenshot.png?dl=0 ). I am not sure why it isn't working for you. Just make sure your bottom constraint has buttonCollectionView as 1st Item and maskView as 2nd item(cause I made an edit).

Comment: I review constraints my storyboard, and everything is ok as yours. Just wrote by code has some wrong. I think, maybe the 'UICollectionView' case this, let's check document on Apple Developer. Thx any way. ^-^